# Incorrect syntax near 'NO'.' in vb.net on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    con.Close()
  End If

  con.Open()

  cmd = con.CreateCommand()
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
  cmd.CommandText = "update Tabledb set FIRSTNAME=" & TextBox1.Text & ",LASTNAME=" & TextBox2.Text & ",PHONE NO=" & TextBox3.Text & ", where Id =" & i & ""
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  cmd.Connection = con
  disp_data()
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you certain the table column is ```PHONE NO```?

Comment: There are several problems with your code. First of all, your values like `FIRSTNAME` are probably strings, but are not enclosed in quotes. Use parametrized queries instead. Second,  your `PHONE NO` column name contains a space. You have to enclose it in `[]` like `[PHONE NO]`

Comment: thank you for your warm welcome, yes the label on the column is PhoneNo

Comment: There is a difference between `phoneno` and `phone no`

Comment: @derpirscher do I need to remove the space on Phone No or put exactly [PHONENO] on coding?

I'm sorry i was just beginner and can't understand some stuffs

Comment: That depends on how the column is really called in the database. You have to use the exact name from the database.

Comment: @LykiaPradilla you have to use `PHONENO` not `PHONE NO`

Comment: on the column of my database it is "PHONE NO."

Comment: should I include the "." on PHONENO. ???

Comment: I removed the space between Phone and no
then include the "." since on my database column it is "PHONENO."

that's what I include. and upon debugging when I press the update button another error appeared 
this error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

Comment: Don't mean o be rude, but if you don't know how to find out, the names of your tables and columns you probably should read some very basic tutorials first ...

Comment: noted sir,
thank you

Comment: You **must** refer to the database columns in your code exactly as they're named in your database, i.e. if the column name in the DB _really_ is `PHONE NO.`, then in your SQL string you need to enclose it in square brackets as noted above: `[PHONE NO.]`. Here's an advice: refrain from using anything but _(plain ANSI)_ **letters** and **numbers** for column names when you design a database. It makes life so much easier.

Comment: On top of that, your code is vulnerable to **SQL injections**. Learn about parametrized queries. Even if you don't care about **security**, your code will choke if the input contains single quotes. Just see what happens with a name like O'Hara. Your SQL statement is broken. I can only reiterate the already stated advice to read some tutorials and learn about best practices. I will spare you the sermon about **naming conventions** for your UI controls. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Give you controls meaningful names. This will make your coding much easier. I have renamed your controls as an example.

You should not have to check `ConnectionState`. Connections, commands and other database objects use unmanaged resources. To release these they provide a `Dispose` method which must be called. These objects should be declared locally in the method where they are used. vb.net provides `Using...End Using` blocks where you declare connections, commands etc. The block will dispose the objects at the `End Using`. (It will also `Close` the connection which you failed to do.)

Don't `Open` the connection until directly before the `.Execute...`.

You can pass the the connection string directly to the connection's constructor. Your can pass the `CommandText` and the `Connection` directly to the constructor of the command.

It is useless to set the `Connection` property of the command after you have attempted to execute the command.

`CommandType.Text` is the default so it is not necessary to set this property explicitly.

**NEVER** concatenate strings to build Sql statements.

**ALWAYS** use parameters.

The field names you use in you Sql string must match exactly the names in the database. That means upper case, lower case, spaces, and periods. If a field name is a reserved word, contains a space or other unusual character is needs to be surrounded by identifier delimiters. For Access and Sql Server that would be brackets [ ]. For MySql use the back tick `. On my USA keyboard that is found below the tilde in the upper left corner. If you are not sure if you need the delimiters you can use them anyway. It won't hurt anything.

I had to guess at the datatypes of the parameters. Check the database for the actual types. I also guessed at the database. Change the code to `OleDb` for Access and `MySql` for MySql.

```
Private OPConStr As String = "Your connection string."

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 5 'I made up a value, don't know where this comes from in the real code
    Dim strSql = "update Tabledb set FIRSTNAME = @FirstName, LASTNAME = @LastName, [PHONENO.] = @Phone, where Id = @ID;"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(OPConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(strSql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPhone.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    disp_data()
End Sub
```